# After ANR,I cant not open_pcm?

Tags: android

I call the tinyalsa JNI to record, when the android program after the ANR, start the program again, call open_pcm method failed, reported IO error, how should it be resolved?

Comment: Can you post some code or an error log?

Comment: ` r->pcm = pcm_open(card, 0, PCM_IN, &r->config);
 if(!r->pcm || !pcm_is_ready(r->pcm)){
  wtk_debug("%s\n",pcm_get_error(r->pcm));
  /**
    * ERROR:cannot set hw params: I/O error
    */
  goto end;
 }
 `